# JS library to bind tags to JSON fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind

I am new in JS, I wonder if there a JS library to bind html fields to JS object, something like:

```
<div class="js_source">
    <input field="name" />
    <input field="surname" />
    <button type="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

By pressing **Save** following JSON generated

```
{"name": "some name", "surname": "some surname"}
```

and sent to the server

I can write this myself obviously, but I would rather use some ready and tested solution :)

Comment: A simple form submit action would do that and post the data to server if required

Comment: Will it automatically convert data to JSON?
General POST has a different format, than that of a JSON

Comment: try using jquery and look out for a a lot of examples available online. And it seems that if you can do it than why wait for some ready and tested solution? You wrote it so it has to perform what you need unless you did something extraordinarily wrong

Comment: There is rule of a thumb to never write solution, if there is already a solution for the problem. This is pretty generic problem, which must have a generic solution, which I'm not aware of, since I only beginner in JS. It's always better to have something tested and used by someone else, and not to invent the wheel again and again.

Comment: try http://knockoutjs.com

Comment: @mavarazy you don't need to write different JS code (and a lot of it) for every project. You can use Jquery Templates => https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl. I have posted code as answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started learning Backbonejs, which in combination with stickit adds this functionality, and much much more.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Jquery Templates. This is a library that binds your HTML template with JSON object. Its a good library and I have used it in several projects. Kindly check it out at =>https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

So your code should look like

```
<script id="Information" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="js_source">
    <input field="${name}" />
    <input field="${surname}" />
    <button type="button">${buttonName}</button>
</div>
</script>
```

The JSON will be the same as posted by you:

```
  var json =  {"name": "some name", "surname": "some surname"};
```

The Javascript code that binds the two will look like:

```
 jsonParsed = $.parseJSON(json);
  $("#Information").tmpl(jsonParsed).appendTo('#AnyDivYouWant');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a extra lib, when you can do this in js

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var json = {};
    json["name"] = $("#name").val();
    json["surname"] = $("#surname").val();
    //usein json to send to server
});
```

I've considered this as your HTML

```
<input id="name" />
<input id="surname" />
```

### Updates:

Using this you can create your own like

```
function createFormJson (formId) { //form id as parameter
    var json = {};
    $("#"+ formId).each(function(){     
        var allIns = $(this).filter(':input'); //iterate to all input types
        allIns.each(function (i, j) {
            var id = $(j).prop('id');
            json[id] = $(this).val();
        });
    });
    return json;
}
```

Comment: That means instead of using one JS library, I'll need to write allot of JS for each form, which is just a waste of time.

Comment: @mavarazy, is it really a waste of time? If you had written this already, you wouldn't be wasting time asking this question (which is explicitly off-topic here), you wouldn't have to spend time to learn that library, and you wouldn't have to spend time eventually writing code to use that library.

Comment: @mavarazy What I tried is to show is that you can create your own generic method of creating json.